# Check a lot of colums for at least one 'true'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a lot of columns (say 200) they are all boolean. I want to know which of those has at least one record set to true. I have come up with the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT  sum(Case When [column1] = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as column1,
sum(Case When [column2] = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as column2, sum(Case
When [column3] = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as column3, FROM [tablename];
```

It will return the number of rows that are 'true' for a column. However, this is more information than I need and thereby maybe a more expensive query then needed. The query keeps scanning all fields for all records even though that would not be necessary.

Comment: Rows have columns, not the other way around. As stated, your question is pretty confusing. Do you have 200 rows, and you want to know if there is at least one where at least one column is 1? Or does each of your rows have 200 columns (I've seen crazier stuff), and you want to know, for each row, if there is at least one column that's 1?

Comment: could do something like `select * from tablename where 1 in (column1, column2, column3)`

Comment: You can try `SELECT MAX(column1) as column1, ... FROM [tablename]`. It sounds like you want to know if any row is true for each column. If thats the case then MAX will return 1 if any row in that column is true.

Comment: I have millions of rows in a table containing 200+ columns. I want to know each column that has at least one row where the column value is 'true'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned something about CHECKSUM(*) that might be useful.   Try the following code:

```
DECLARE  @T TABLE (
b1 bit
,b2 bit
,b3 bit
);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (
b1 bit
,b2 bit
,b3 bit
,b4 bit
,b5 bit
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (0,0,0),(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1,1);

SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM @T;
SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM @T2;
```

You will see from the results that no matter how many columns are in a row, if they are all bit columns with a value of 0, the result of CHECKSUM(*) is always 0.

This means that you could use `WHERE CHECKSUM(*)<>0` in your query to save the engine the trouble of summing rows where all the values are 0.   Might improve performance.

And even if it doesn't, it's a neat thing to know.

EDIT:

You could do an EXISTS() function on each column.   I understand that the EXISTS() function stops scanning when it finds a value that exists.   If you have more rows than columns, it might be more performant.  If you have more columns than rows, then your current query using SUM() on every column is probably the fastest thing you can do.

Comment: Even if `CHECKSUM` is always 0 when all columns are 0, it doesn't necessarily follow that it is not 0 if any columns are not 0. You'd have to dig into the implementation for that. (Rigorously testing all 2^200 possible combinations is out, I'm afraid...) For example, a trivial checksum that performed an `XOR` on all the columns (which is not the actual checksum, but bear with me) would be 0 on every even number of 1s, even if it's also 0 on all 0.

Comment: I don't know what an XOR would look like in terms of TSQL syntax, but if you use * as the sole argument to CHECKSUM, you use all columns in the row.   I'm not about to test every combination of 200 bit columns, you're right, but I'll eat my hat if you can find a way to get a CHECKSUM(*) of zero when any of the columns have a value of 1.  That would mean that the two rows with different values would have identical CHECKSUMs, which would defeat the purpose of CHECKSUM, and, to my (admittedly limited) understanding, is impossible.

Comment: `XOR` in T-SQL is `^`. But I don't really care about your willingness to digest headgear -- I wouldn't stake the correctness of any solution on the dearth of imagination of any individual developer. `CHECKSUM`'s collision properties are notoriously bad; I really don't have much trouble believing that there can be column combinations where it fails to properly distribute the input bits, even though it has plenty of output bits available. Shifting the burden of finding an example to me is fine, but I'm not going to check all combinations either, if you don't mind. :-)

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. `CHECKSUM` outputs an `INT`. It has only 32 bits available. Therefore, if rows have more than 32 bits of information available, there *must* be rows with different column contents that nevertheless have the same checksum, simply because there are not enough different checksums to distinguish them. This is true for any checksum, not just the one implemented by `CHECKSUM`, and is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189788).  A checksum can never be used to conclude rows are definitely identical, only that they're definitely not.

Comment: Note that you're not asking for `CHECKSUM` to reliably distinguish between two rows with 200 bits (which isn't possible); you're asserting the weaker property that `CHECKSUM` will never be 0 if any input bits are 1 (which *is* possible, but requires that you know the algorithm to be able to conclude that this definitely is the case).

Comment: I don't mind at all.   If it's possible for 2 rows with different values to produce the same CHECKSUM, then your caveat is valid.  I concede that I don't know definitely that it is not possible for any combination of 200 bits to have some combination of 1's & 0's that would produce the same CHECKSUM as all zeros.   Still I believe that I have learned something useful and shared it.   But as always, test before employing in production.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #t(A BIT NOT NULL, B BIT NOT NULL, C BIT NOT NULL, D BIT NOT NULL, E BIT NOT NULL, F BIT NOT NULL, G BIT NOT NULL, H BIT NOT NULL, I BIT NOT NULL); INSERT #T(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I) VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM #t;`. Could you make it a top hat? I've always wanted to see someone eat a top hat. :-)

Comment: That is interesting!   I don't own a top hat, but I'll see if I can find a chocolate bunny wearing one.

Comment: Good to know indeed! However, it does not answer my question. It returns all rows with at least one column true in stead of all column with at least one row with the column value true.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have 200 columns/fields on one table with boolean then something like the following should work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 + column2  + column3 + ... + column200 >= 1 THEN 'Something was true for this record' ELSE NULL END AS My_Big_Field_Test 
FROM  [TableName];
```

Comment: greater than equal to 1 (>= 1)

Comment: that's a good idea. Updated. Although... based on the interpretations of the query and the comments on the question, this probably isn't matching OP's needs. :/

Comment: You'll have to add `CAST(column1 AS INT)` everywhere, since arithmetic on `BIT` fields isn't allowed. (Which I'm assuming is what the OP means when he talks about "booleans".)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the rows that have at last one boolean field, you will need to test every of them.

Something like this (maybe):

```
SELECT ROW.*
FROM TABLE ROW
WHERE ROW.COLUMN_1 = 1 
OR ROW.COLUMN_2 = 1 
OR ROW.COLUMN_3 = 1 
OR ... 
OR ROW.COLUMN_N = 1;
```

Comment: No, that is not what I want to know. I want to know all column names that have at least one row with a value 'true' for that column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my machine, but you could also try the bitwise or operator:

```
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE column1 | column2 | column3 = 1
```

The OR answer from Arthur is the other suggestion I would offer. Try a few different suggestions and look at the query plans. Also take a look at disk reads and CPU usage. (SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON).

See whatever method gives the desires results and the best performance...and then let us know :-)

Comment: That will return all rows where at least one column value is true. I want all column names where there is at least one row where the column value is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query of the form

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Column1] = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Column1',
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Column2] = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Column2',
    ...
```

The efficiency of this critically depends on how sparse your table is. If there are columns where every single row has a `0` value, then any query that searches for a `1` value will require a full table scan, unless an index is in place. A really good choice for this scenario (millions of rows and hundreds of columns) is a [columnstore index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg492153). These are supported from SQL Server 2012 onwards; from SQL Server 2014 onwards they don't cause the table to be read-only (which is a major barrier to their adoption).

With a columnstore index in place, each subquery should require constant time, and so should the query as a whole (in fact, with hundreds of columns, this query gets so big that you might run into trouble with the input buffer and need to split it up into smaller queries). Without indexes, this query can still be effective as long as the table isn't sparse -- if it "quickly" runs into a row with a `1` value, it stops.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Regrettably, the table is 'sparse' in this regard. We are migrating to a in memory table with a columnstore index in a few months.